# Android:Change Language Accordinglly

Tags: android, locale

i am creating App. that contains Sign-Up form. i want to change language as per click(select) language from spinner. is it possible?

any help?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

Hope this helps you.